# vuetify v-hover conflict with Animation on Scroll (aos)

Tags: vuetify.js

I want hover and aos effect on a v-card element, like:

```
      <v-hover v-slot:default="{hover}">
        <v-card
          data-aos="flip-up"
          data-aos-once="true"
          :elevation="hover?12:2"
          >
          <v-card-title></v-card-title>
          <v-card-text></v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-hover>
```

But the two effects seems conflict with each other. When I hover on the element, the aos animation also triggers.

I have tried to add the hover and AOS animation on different level of element, but it results in not showing anything on mobile when I set the AOS diabled on phone. like:

```
    <v-row data-aos="flip-up" data-aos-once="true">
        <v-hover v-slot:default="{hover}">
            <v-card
              data-aos="flip-up"
              data-aos-once="true"
              :elevation="hover?12:2"
              >
              <v-card-title></v-card-title>
              <v-card-text></v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-hover>
    </v-row>
```

I think it related to this [issue](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/issues/335),but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I use aos@next, and set useClassName to true, with the second snippet, seems to work for now.